# Compilation failed: unknown property name after \P

Tags: php, pcre

Using PHP 5.3.1, PCRE is enabled and is version 7.9 2009-04-11.

```
$string = preg_replace("/\p{Number}/u", "", $string);
```

produces the error:
Compilation failed: unknown property name after \P . . .

I understand this was a bug that is fixed in PHP 5.3 and up but I obviously get it as do others using my scripts.  As far as I can make out, it might be something to do with the version of PCRE that is being used or how it was compiled.

I have no control over the compiled version of PHP that is being used.

1. Is there a way to check in the PHP script if PCRE has been compiled correctly?
2. I'm also using:

   preg_match("/\p{Lu}/u", $caseChar);
   preg_match("/\p{Ll}/u", $caseChar);
   preg_match("/\p{L}/u", $string, $caseChar);

If incorrect PCRE has been found (if 1. is possible), is there an alternative to the above preg_replace and preg_match expressions?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 5):

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

`\p{Number}` is not a supported property code as per the above. It's `\p{N}` or even just `\pN`.